# Rails caches class variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model in which I want to implement scope tracking functionality (e.g. which scopes have been applied), I need this in order to apply another scopes conditionally. So, I decided to create an instance variable on a class level which will hold an array of symbols which correspond to scope names. Every time when the scope is being applied, its symbol is pushed into the array. So the problem is that I'm expecting the array to be initialized on every request. But as far as I understand rails is caching all classes (still the `cache_classes` option is turned off) and this results in a behavior where the array contents are saved between requests, so when I change the scopes to be applied (they are applied conditionally, depending on `GET` parameters), I find old scope symbols in that array, instead of the new ones. And maybe after several requests I can see new results, but it happens randomly. So my hypothetical code is the following:

```
class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
  @scopes = []
  def self.scopes
    @scopes
  end

  scope :green, -> { scopes << :green }
end
```

I've tried different combinations of variables (class variables, class instance variables, defining accessors and variables on eigenclass, maybe something else - I don't remember), tried to create a duplicate of array or creating an array with `Array.new` method but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you can just clear this array in a before_filter

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :clear_scope_history

  private

  def clear_scope_history
    Apple.scopes.clear
    # Banana.scopes.clear
    # etc.
  end
end
```

By the way, `scopes` is a bad choice for name of your method. Will likely overwrite one from ActiveRecord. Rename it to `scope_usage_history` or something like that.

Comment: Yeah, I can do it this way, but it looks like a not very nice approach. And the problem is still there, why does it behave like this? And how can I overcome it gracefully?

Comment: Well, rails probably doesn't reload classes if a file hasn't changed (for performance reasons). You could get fancy and turn the code above into a module, sprinkled with metaprogramming magic. Wouild look nicer, I imagine. But this one is simple as rock. Not the least important characteristic for legacy code. :)

Comment: Btw, it doesn't work :( I mean, on every request I get an empty array.

Comment: Yes, because you clear it before the request. If you use scopes like you shown in the question, by the end of request, you should get correct history.

Comment: "So the problem is that I'm expecting the array to be initialized on every request." - do you or do you not want array be empty on each new request?

Comment: Also, `scopes` is a bad choice for your method. Will likely overwrite one from ActiveRecord. Use `scope_usage_history` or something

Comment: I mean the array remains empty even the scopes being applied. The algorithm should be the following: request -> initialize empty array -> apply scope and push scope symbol to array. But with your code, the array is empty for the lifetime of the request

Comment: I've tried `scopess` just as a proof of concept and the behavior was the same :)

Comment: If you can share a minimal example, I'll try to debug it. :) I do mean "minimal"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65298/discussion-between-dima-knivets-and-sergio-tulentsev).

Comment: so, what do you think?

Comment: I didn't see an example :)

Comment: Yeah, nothing jumps out at me. Should work (at a first glance).

Comment: didn't I answer that in the comment above?